# UPS power cord is giving electric shock only when computer is running using UPS back up power supply

Tags: display, cpu, desktop-computer, ups

I brought a new desktop along with an UPS. I plugged monitor power cord and CPU power cord both in UPS and **UPS is not connected to any power supply**. Then I have Started the UPS and my computer started running using UPS’s back up charge.

But when I touched the power supply cord of UPS it was giving electric shock.

*Then I just unplugged the monitor power cord and CPU power cord, now UPS power cord is not giving any electric shock.*

Is this usual behavior or something went wrong?  Something went wrong in UPS or CPU or Monitor. Can any one please explain me what is going on.

Already I have to change the power supply for this desktop as it got damaged due to some unknown issue, so I don't want to face similar problem again. Kindly suggest and explain me on this.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99936/discussion-on-question-by-bacteria-ups-power-cord-is-giving-electric-shock-only).

Answer (score 0):

At this point, you need to get the unit serviced if you are the least bit unsure (as noted above in the comments).  I have my own UPS and my clients have them and we simply do not get electric shocks from them.

Good luck with your unit